# How to allocate dynamic memory for self referential structure in c?

Tags: c, data-structures

Which is the correct way of allocating memory?
What happens in both cases?

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};  
typedef struct Node *node;
int main() {
    node head = (node)malloc(sizeof(node));//line 1
    node head = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));//line 2
}
```

Comment: Don't typedef pointers, please. That is what is confusing you.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but what happens if we allocate so??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that it's self-refential is of no importance. The issue with your first attempt is that your `typedef` is hiding a pointer. So `node` and `struct Node`, in your code, are two different things. The first allocates room for a pointer to `struct Node`, and the second allocates room for a `struct Node`.

The prefered way to do memory allocation is to use the `*` operator to implicitly get the type of the pointed variable, like this:

```
node head = malloc(sizeof *head);
```

The `sizeof` operator is smart enought to not try to "follow" the pointer to find the size of `*head`. It just checks its type.

Notice that I also ditched the cast. There is no need to cast the result of `malloc()` in C. In fact, it is a bad idea to do so, because it can hide some problems if you forget to `#include` a header.

Additionally, I  suggest you **don't** hide pointers with `typedef`s. It makes the code less readable because you'll have things that don't look like pointer but must be handled like pointers (exception: if you really want opaque objects and sometimes function pointers).

So here's my full suggestion to you:

```
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};
typedef struct node Node;

int main() {
    Node *head = malloc(sizeof *head);
}
```

Comment: Note about the *"don't hide pointers with `typedef`s"*: It's definitely OK, and even recommended for readability, with function pointers. (I know the question isn't about that, but if you're saying this as a general rule...)

Comment: Please explain the difference between line1 and line2 and their significance in detail

Comment: The first line is like `malloc(sizeof (struct Node*))` and the second is like `malloc(sizeof (struct Node))`

Comment: Yeah but what happens in both cases, will that be fine or will there be any unwanted behaviour?

Comment: The second is right. The first is wrong: `head` is pointing to something that has the wrong size. So undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

In your scenario your second approach is the valid one.

In the first try you are allocating the size of a pointer for the structure, but you want to reserve as many bytes as you need to save the whole structure and not a pointer to it.

So go with

```
node head = (node)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

and you are fine.

Comment: Why not `node head = malloc(sizeof(*node));`?

Comment: @JL2210 Because that doesn't compile..., you mean `node head = malloc(sizeof(*head));`?